# How many 'idols' did Francis Bacon identify?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, bertrand-russell, francis-bacon

The majority of references to Francis Bacon's 'idols' refer to 4 distinct ones but some sources have otherwise. There is a supposed 5th, that is 'idols of the schools'. Which is correct? Did Bacon ever enumerate them all or are these interpretations based on common themes in his work?

I found this inconsistency in two different versions of Bertrand Russell's 'History of Western Philosophy'. And on subsequent searches there appears to be two versions of these rules/'idols'.

Comment: Regarding the list of four Idols in [Novum Organum](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/francis-bacon/#Ido); and see also [idola mentis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baconian_method#Idols_of_the_mind_(idola_mentis))

Comment: Source: Francis Bacon, [The New Organon (1620), Engl.transl. Cambridge University Press (2000), Book I, XXXIX (page 40)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Francis_Bacon_The_New_Organon/MUm8Yzmq5NUC): "There are four kinds of illusions which block men’s minds. For instruction’s sake, we have given them the following names: the first kind are called idols of the tribe; the second idols of the cave; the third idols of the marketplace; the fourth idols of the theatre."

Comment: I see, is there a traceable origin to the 5th 'idol' misnomer, or whether it is even a misnomer? Or is it Bacon himself that has inconsistencies with his other texts?

Comment: "is there a traceable origin to the 5th 'idol' misnomer?" The issue is: what is the source of your information?

Comment: There are many hits with a Google search but here is one of the hits from a scholarly article: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2709705. "Yet this same Baconian investigator can at times be a pure and brilliant mirror, an angel and not a torturer. All that is required is that he free himself from the domination of idols of the understanding, whether the linguistic *idols of the schools*, the idols of the theater represented by the men with theories, or the distorting power of the emotions." - p95

Comment: A very historically significant source of this 5th idol is in one of the versions of Russell's book, [History of Western Philosophy](http://www.ntslibrary.com/PDF%20Books/History%20of%20Western%20Philosophy.pdf). Page 544: "Lastly there are "idols of the schools," which consist in thinking that
some blind rule (such as the syllogism) can take the place of judgement in investigation."

Answer (score 1):

They are four; see Francis Bacon, [The New Organon (1620), Engl.transl. Cambridge University Press (2000)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Francis_Bacon_The_New_Organon/MUm8Yzmq5NUC), Book I, XXXIX (page 40):

> "There are four kinds of illusions which block men’s minds. For instruction’s sake, we have given them the following names: the first kind are called idols of the tribe; the second idols of the cave; the third idols of the marketplace; the fourth idols of the theatre."

IMO the source for the "five idols" list is the original (1945) edition of Russell's *History* (see the [1947 edition, page 566](https://archive.org/details/westernphilosoph035502mbp/page/566/mode/2up)), later corrected.

The Routledge edition has: "One of the most famous parts of Bacon's philosophy is his enumeration of what he calls 'idols', by which he means bad habits of mind that cause people to fall into error. Of these he enumerates *four* kinds."

Comment: Much appreciated. It would be interesting to know the origin of this misnomer, as it's not as if a mistranslation would result in a change from 4 to 5.